# covariant derivative of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Here's one question concerning notations. For a vector field $X=T^j\frac{\partial}{\partial u_j}$, I know
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial u_j}}X=(\frac{\partial T^k}{\partial u_i}+\Gamma_{ij}^k T^j)\frac{\partial}{\partial u_k}.$$

But  what is this:
$$\nabla X=\mathrm{d}u^i\otimes\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}}X?$$
I have consulted many DG books, but in vain. Can anyone tell me what this is called and where I can find it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the covariant derivative without feeding it a vector field, so it's a vector-field-valued $1$-form. If you want to compute the covariant derivative in the direction of a vector field $V$, you compute
$$\nabla_V X=(\nabla X)(V) = \left(\sum du^j\otimes \nabla_{\partial/\partial u^j} X\right)(V) = \sum du^j(V) \nabla_{\partial/\partial u^j} X.$$
In particular, when $V=\partial/\partial u^i$, you get
$$\nabla_{\partial/\partial u^i} X = \sum \delta_i^j \nabla_{\partial/\partial u^j} X = \nabla_{\partial/\partial u^i} X,$$
which is perhaps not particularly interesting or surprising :)

Comment: Does this depend on the choice of coordinates $\{u_i\}$?

Comment: $\nabla_V X$ does not depend on the choice of coordinates, but $\nabla_{\partial / \partial u^i} X$ depends on the coordinates $(u^i)$.

Comment: Why? How do I prove this? Thanks.

Comment: Note that if $d\tilde u^i =\sum a^i_j du^j$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\tilde u^k} = \sum b_k^\ell\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u^\ell}$, then $\sum a^i_\ell b_k^\ell = \delta^i_k$. Now write out $\sum d\tilde u^i\otimes \nabla_{\partial/\partial\tilde u^i}$.